# Query which QT element has focus

Tags: qt

Is it possible to query which QT element currently has focus?

I'm currently working with a program and the action I want to implement requires a specific element to have focus.  Instead of trying to track down through the hierarchy from the top which element I need, I'm wondering if it's possible to select the element in the UI and then query it so that I can trace it's path upwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know that QWidget has the focus then use the [`QApplication::focusWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#focusWidget) method, you can also use the [`focusChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#focusChanged) signal